# C++: Destructor not called with embedded template

Tags: c++, templates, destructor

Short: deleting a templatized pointer does not call the destructor.

## include  solves the problem. Why?

I just ran into a situation that I can't explain. I try to break the more complex situation down here.

File R.cpp

```
class R {
      Owner<Problem> m_o;
      void cleanUp() { m_o.clear(); }
     }
```

File Owner.cpp

```
struct DeleteFunctor {
  template< class TPtr > void operator()(TPtr* ptr) {  delete ptr; }
};

template< class T >
class Owner { 
std::vector<T*> m_objects; 
// here add and other stuff
void clear() {
  std::for_each( m_objects.begin(), m_objects.end(), DeleteFunctor() );
  m_objects.clear();
}
```

I now have a utility class that creates new Problem-objects on the heap and inserts them into m_o directly. I know that it's bad style to export references to internal types but that's not the point.

If I call cleanUp() I can trace it down up to the call delete ptr in the Functor, with ptr having the correct Problem-type. But the Problem-destructor is not called!!

However, including the Problem header in file R.cpp fixes the problem. The comiler does not complain. Is that a compiler bug?

System:
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2

Comment: Why not `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`?

Comment: What's T likely to be in this context?

Comment: Adding or removing lines of code like that and then seeing different behavior is an indication that you have a memory corruption bug.  All you're really doing is changing the executable image, moving the bug around to a different part of your program.  So you really haven't fixed the problem.

Comment: you are calling `m_o.clear()` in `R::cleanUp()` not `R::~R()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the standard (draft n3242) §5.3.5/5:

> If the object being deleted has incomplete class type at the point of deletion and the complete class has a non-trivial destructor or a deallocation function, the behavior is undefined.

If you don't include the header which defines `T` or `Problem` in this case, then you're deleting an object of incomplete type. If that type does not fulfill the requirements in that clause, then the deletion has undefined behaviour.

> Is that a compiler bug?

No, compilers are not required to warn about undefined behaviour.

You may want to require `T` of `Owner` to be complete. Something like `static_assert(sizeof(T) > 0)` should fail to compile if `T` is incomplete.

If you can't rely on the current standard, you can instead use `boost::checked_deleter` as your delete functor. It does the completeness check in pre c++11. If you for some reason don't want to include a boost header, then just reimplement it. This is the code which checks for completeness.

```
// intentionally complex - simplification causes regressions
typedef char type_must_be_complete[ sizeof(T)? 1: -1 ];
(void) sizeof(type_must_be_complete);
delete x;
```

Note that you're effectively partially re-implementing `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` If you can use c++11, I recommend to use that instead.

Comment: Where does this appear in the standard? Can you edit?

Comment: And of course this makes sense - if you show me a chunk of memory and say "delete the foobar here", unless I know how big a foobar is who knows what I'm doing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing that out. C++11 is unfortunatly not an option :( How do I avoid running in this situation? This could be a debbuging nightmare for a complex project.

Comment: @user4575239 if your template doesn't do anything else that would require the type to be complete (such as construction etc.) then as far as I know, your best bet is to use a trick to test the completeness. Boost has checked_deleter which uses such trick.